# Java/Swing (and GUI in general) - technique or patterns to build dynamic search form with criterias/filters

Tags: java, user-interface, search, forms, dynamic

I feel recurrent the need of building a search formula or filter panel using logic and expression.

Here are some example expressions:
search all item with price >= $100 and available in stock.
filter all files with (name like *.log or name = toto.txt) and modification date < 2 hours from now

I know how to implement such a search/filtering pattern for performing the search, but I hand code the gui part, losing a lot of possibilities (and/or stuff, ...).

Does someone know a generic way of building this kind of dynamic form allowing user to create its own request graphically ? 
In this kind of form the user will be able to select which criteria are relevant, enter its own values and create logical expression.

Answer (score 1):

The JBoss Rules Guvnor [interface](http://downloads.jboss.com/drools/docs/5.0.1.26597.FINAL/drools-guvnor/html/ch01.html) provides a way to build your own criteria (albeit not for searching). If you have an instance of Thunderbird at hand, it's [search criteria builder](http://weblogs.asp.net/blogs/rchartier/WindowsLiveWriter/ThunderbirdSearchFoldersStarredItems_8342/SearchMessages_thumb.png) is quite similar. This is a fairly common pattern, but it's not one I tend to implement for enterprise applications.

Comment: Thanks for the Drools Guvnor link, that's a great source for rules management. I have a deeper look on this.